# Add off click and escape functionality to fadeToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to have the ability to re-activate the fadeToggle to close if it detects an off canvas click or the esc button is pressed.

http://jsfiddle.net/sj6kdyLk/

```
$("#name").click(function() {
$("#about").fadeToggle(500, "linear");
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
   if($('#about').css === 'block'){
     $('#about').hide(200)
   }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#about').css` wont work in this case. You should use `is(':visible')`, so your code should look like:

```
if ($('#about').is(':visible')) {
...
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sj6kdyLk/2/